PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of exhausted - Drupal 7
I checked the php-fpm log and received the following message:
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 28672 bytes) in /home/....com/public_html/.../includes/cache.inc on line 361
 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /home/....com/public_html/.../includes/database/database.inc on line 731
 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in /home/....com/public_html/.../includes/cache.inc on line 449
 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in /home/....com/public_html/.../includes/cache.inc on line 449
 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in /home/....com/public_html/.../includes/cache.inc on line 449
 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/....com/public_html/.../includes/cache.inc on line 449
 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in /home/....com/public_html/.../includes/cache.inc on line 449
 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /home/....com/public_html/.../includes/database/database.inc on line 2284

# function contains line 361
 function getMultiple(&$cids) {
    try {
      // Garbage collection necessary when enforcing a minimum cache lifetime.
      $this->garbageCollection($this->bin);

      // When serving cached pages, the overhead of using db_select() was found
      // to add around 30% overhead to the request. Since $this->bin is a
      // variable, this means the call to db_query() here uses a concatenated
      // string. This is highly discouraged under any other circumstances, and
      // is used here only due to the performance overhead we would incur
      // otherwise. When serving an uncached page, the overhead of using
      // db_select() is a much smaller proportion of the request.
      $result = db_query('SELECT cid, data, created, expire, serialized FROM {' . db_escape_table($this->bin) . '} WHERE cid IN (:cids)', array(':cids' => $cids));
      $cache = array();
// #361     
 foreach ($result as $item) { 
        $item = $this->prepareItem($item);
        if ($item) {
          $cache[$item->cid] = $item;
        }
      }
      $cids = array_diff($cids, array_keys($cache));
      return $cache;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
      // If the database is never going to be available, cache requests should
      // return FALSE in order to allow exception handling to occur.
      return array();
    }
  }

#function contains line 449
protected function prepareItem($cache) {
    global $user;

    if (!isset($cache->data)) {
      return FALSE;
    }
    // If the cached data is temporary and subject to a per-user minimum
    // lifetime, compare the cache entry timestamp with the user session
    // cache_expiration timestamp. If the cache entry is too old, ignore it.
    if ($cache->expire != CACHE_PERMANENT && variable_get('cache_lifetime', 0) && isset($_SESSION['cache_expiration'][$this->bin]) && $_SESSION['cache_expiration'][$this->bin] > $cache->created) {
      // Ignore cache data that is too old and thus not valid for this user.
      return FALSE;
    }

    // If the data is permanent or not subject to a minimum cache lifetime,
    // unserialize and return the cached data.
//#449
    if ($cache->serialized) {
      $cache->data = unserialize($cache->data);
    }

    return $cache;
  }

My current php.ini file is as follows:
PHP version:    7.4.33
PHP memory_limit:   4G
PHP post_max_size:  16M
PHP upload_max_filesize:    4M
PHP max_input_vars: 1000
PHP max_execution_time: 60
And:
OS: Almalinux 9,
webserver: Apache
Drupal version: V 7.101

I tried adjusting the memory_limit parameter in php.ini to 7GB and received the following error message
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 7516192768 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /home/.....com/public_html/..../includes/cache.inc on line 361
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 7516192768 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/.....com/public_html/..../includes/cache.inc on line 449
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 7516192768 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/.....com/public_html/..../includes/cache.inc on line 449
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 7516192768 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/.....com/public_html/..../includes/cache.inc on line 449
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 7516192768 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/.....com/public_html/..../includes/cache.inc on line 449
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 7516192768 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /home/.....com/public_html/..../includes/database/database.inc on line 731

I don't understand where the error comes from, please help me. I tried changing it by setting memory_limit = -1 and my server crashed after 24 hours

if you do $lengthData = db_query('SELECT cid, LENGTH(data), created, expire, LENGTH(serialized) FROM {' . db_escape_table($this->bin) . '} WHERE cid IN (:cids)', array(':cids' => $cids)); error_log(var_export($lengthData,true));, what error message do you get right before the crash?

and what do you get from the query SELECT MAX(LENGTH(data)), MAX(LENGTH(serialized)) FROM `table`; ?

I agree with the other posters.  The problem stems from whatever this query is producing:
$result = db_query('SELECT cid, data, created, expire, serialized 
FROM {' . db_escape_table($this->bin) . '} 
WHERE cid IN (:cids)', array(':cids' => $cids));

You need to figure out a way to profile that query because it is clearly producing a result set that is practically infinite in size with respect to your individual query limit (16Mb) and application total memory footprint (4Gb).  If you are storing media in the data field (i.e. 4K film clips) you can easily outstrip these memory limits.
My advice is to open up MySQL and start poking around.
If you are not a back-end type of person, look at the columns being selected:
SELECT 
cid,          # usually a primary key (small)
data,         # usually a record payload (BIG)
created,      # usually a timestamp (small)
expire,       # usually a timestamp (small)
serialized    # usually serialized data (BIG)

Without even knowing the column data types, it looks like you only have two suspects to check out...both potentially related to (unlimited) DATA:
data
serialized

So, to me, it looks like your record payload(s) may be something big because there is a 50/50 chance that whatever you are storing in "data" may be a payload rather than a pointer to a payload, and "serialized" is usually a flattened data structure (i.e. a payload).
